# An alternative for sp_unbinddefault

Tags: sql-server-2008, default-value

I have a column with default value bound to `UW_ZeroDefault` and I am trying get rid of it.

As I understand it, this default has been created by using [CREATE DEFAULT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173565.aspx) then the column has been bound to this default by using `sp_bindefault`.

Usually to remove this default, you would use `sp_unbinddefault`, but since there is a bug in SQL Server 2008 (see [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/961803)), I am getting an error:

> Invalid object name ' '.

I cannot make any changes to the SQL Server installation, so I am looking for some workarround how to drop this thing.

### Summary of the discusion below:

**SOLUTION 1:**

As suggested by @gbn, if you can get your database back to the SQL Server 2000, do it and use `sp_unbindefault` there. That should work.

But if you can't move it (that's my case)...

**SOLUTION 2:**

Make a copy of the table(s) and use `CONSTRAINT` to set a default instead of binding default. This includes dropping all kind of constraints, FKs, etc. and recreating them afterwards. It is a bad solution, but I couldn't find a better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [BOL rather than KB, use ALTER TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188913.aspx)

```
ALTER TABLE Mytable DROP <defaultname>;
```

The name of the default could be user supplied or system generated. 
To find it and generate the SQL needed:

```
SELECT
    OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id), dc.name,
    'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(c.object_id)) + ' DROP ' + QUOTENAME(dc.name);
FROM
    sys.columns c
    JOIN
    sys.default_constrainst dc ON c.columnid = dc.parent_column_id AND c.object_id = dc.parent_object_id
WHERE
    c.name = 'UW_ZeroDefault';
```

Comment: `UW_ZeroDefault` is not a constraint. It was created using [CREATE DEFAULT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173565.aspx) then bound with `sp_bindefault` and should be unbind by using [sp_unbindefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188913.aspx). But that doesn't work in my case.

Comment: @Radek Stromský: have you tried ALTER TABLE? You may have to remove it in SQL Server 2000 first.

Comment: yeah, I've tried, but with no success. I assume that `sp_unbindefault` would work on SQL Server 2000, but in our current stage, we are unable to migrate database back from the SQL Server 2008 to 2000. It would be simpler for us to make a clone of the entire table and drop the one with the "cursed default value".

Comment: @Radek Stromský: unfortunately, that is your solution then. Rules and this kind of default were archaic in SQL Server 2000.